# Grails springSecurityService how to set current user

Tags: grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have authenticated users through spring oauth.So once i get their email and user name using the access token, I will crosscheck if a user in my user table exist with those credentials, If so i wanted to set that user as the current user in spring security.so is that possible

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate(user.username)
```